# How to use execl?

Tags: c++, c, exec

I saw the following usage of `execl`:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "-R", "-a", NULL);
```

I'm wondering why the first parameter is ls, it's already in the first parameter why to add it again?

can it be NULL? what's the impact?

Comment: I am wondering why you did not see its documentation, its already there, why to ask it again?

Can it be tried? what was the impact?

Comment: The first argument after `pathname`  is what the program itself (`/bin/ls` in this case) will see in `argv[0]`. If you'd make it `NULL` that would act as a termiator in the `argv` array.

Comment: There need not be any relationship between the executable name and what is passed as `argv[0]`.  It would be legitimate (but weird) to use `execl("/bin/ls", "elephant", "-l", "does-not-exist", (char *)0);`.  When I run that, I get the error message `elephant: does-not-exist: No such file or directory`.  The `ls` program got told that its name is `elephant` and it used that in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the execl's man document like below.

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ... /* (char  *) NULL */);

The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.  Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated  strings  that represent the argument list available to the executed program.  **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.**  The list of arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.
```

The first parameter points to the filename associated with the file being executed.

BR,